# Adding data into database from user control using a button

Tags: c#, database, addition

I'd like to add data into one of my tables in the database with a button on a user control. The data that I would like to add into the table are from textboxes, that the user can fill up.
Here is the code:

```
   private void rendelj_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rendeles ar = new Rendeles();
        ar.aid = (akusztikus_listBox.SelectedValue).ToString();
        ar.Megrendelo = nev_textBox.Text;
        ar.Email = email_textBox.Text;
        ar.Telefonszam = telefonszam_textBox.Text;
        ar.Fizetett_osszeg = arTextBox.Text;            

        db.Rendeles.AddObject(ar);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }    
}
```

Can you help me with this one?

Comment: Are you using asp.net webforms or asp.net mvc or winforms. Also this question ist covered in many basic tutorials. So where are you stuck and what have you tried?

Comment: Also, could you clean your code from those strange characters?

Comment: I cleaned the code (I guess if those were the characters you mentioned:), and where I am stuck.. Well with this code, when I click on the button I don't get any kind of error but when I stop the running of the program and I check the data in the table it shows me that nothing was inserted there. And I think I am using winforms. (I am not a professional on this subject:D)

Comment: Can you check in the immediate window if 'ar' has a modified state of "Added".   I'd hazard a guess you are using EF?

Comment: So, I checked. There is no Added state and yes, I am using entity framework.